# Ограничение на показ страницы

Tags: html, php

Доброго всем времени суток.

Можно ли написать web страницу так, что бы она проверяла, запущена ли она через iframe/include, и если да, то адрес сайта, с которого она запущена... И если это не тот, который у меня, то естественно принять определенные действия.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Иногда делают вложенный js примерно такого содержания

```
var myPlace = 'http://mysite.ru/'
if (top.location != document.location) {
  // фрейм
  top.location = document.location; // простое перенаправление домой
  }
if (top.location.substr(0, myPlace.length) != myPlace) {
  // парсер/url_include
  top.location = myPlace+'alarm.php?d='+document.domain; // стукач =) В файле alarm.php можно записать где-нибудь домен злодея и перенаправить юзера, опять же, на mysite.ru
  }
```

На уровне пхп отследить сложновато, т.к. адекватные парсеры от браузера слабо отличаются.

На вопрос в каменте, **UPD**

Вообще выше - лайт-версия, подходящая для большинства сайтов. Если JS отключен, вы вряд ли что-то сделаете. НО если включен: Вот вам более-менее близкое к профессиональному решение.

**Раз:** делаем отдельную папку со скриптами.

**Два:** делаем скрипт примерно такого содержания (fetch.php)

```
// ваши переменные
$security = 'скрипт выше, замените действия на нужные вам';
$scriptDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/js/'; // папка со скриптами
$trash = array('var a = "15";', 'if (typeof(c)=="undefined") var c = 29138;'); // можно добавить еще горы мусора, только не пихайте сильно нагружающие.

// дальше можно не трогать
$security_included = false;
$scriptDirScanned = scandir($scriptDir);
$scriptsCount = count($scriptDirScanned)-2;

// подготовка кода (добавляем мусора)
for ($i = 0; $i < rand(3, 8); $i++)
  $security = str_replace(';', ';'.$trash[rand(0, count($trash)-1)]);
$nSecure = rand(1, $scriptsCount);
$n = 0;

// говорим браузеру, что это js
header('Content-Type: text/javascript;charset=utf-8');
header('Pragma: No-Cache');

// выводим все скрипты и в случайном месте нашу секьюрити
foreach($scriptDirScanned as $f)
  if (substr($f, -3, 3)=='.js') {
    $n++;
    if (!$security_included && ($n >= $nSecure)) {
      echo $security;
      $security_included = true;
      }
    echo file_get_contents($scriptDir.'/'.$f);
    }

if (!$security_included) 
  echo $security; // на всякий случай
```

**Три:** включаем этот файл в ваш сайт (остальной js можно вырубить, скрипт их сам включит)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.ru/js/fetch.php"></script>
<!-- обязательно пишите полный путь -->
```

Все. Имеем вложенный скрипт, без которого не будут работать все остальные и который при должном количестве мусора сложно распарсить.

Comment: с применением js 2 беды: 1. если js отключена, нужно проверить; 2. нужно сделать не пере направление, а переменную, типа $mesto = "тут я сам придумаю что", т.к. выбор действия я хочу сделать сам, на основании значений переменной. можно как то значение из js передать в php?

Comment: Обновил.

Comment: супер!